# Keeping user's API secret of SHA secured in db

Tags: security, hash, client-server, sha

I have a mobile app communicating with server over HTTPS. Upon successful signup I return the app a unique API secret to be saved locally on the device. This API secret is used for all private method calls made to server following successful signup from this user.

In the header of each request made to server I put:

```
"key":  username
"sign": (SHA256 of post_parameters using API secret)
```

Server takes the post_parameters and SHA256 using the username's unique API secret found in db. If result matches "sign" then access is granted.

My question is this:

How do I keep each user's unique API secret safe on server db? If someone gets access to usernames and their API secrets, he has full control of user's account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the hash of the secret in the database, but require the user to provide the secret. That way, if the database leaks, then an attacker has the hash, but doesn't have the secret itself. When the user logs on, hash the secret that the user provides, and check whether it matches the stored hash.

To make it more secure yet, you could consider using *salt*: store a random value (in plaintext) in the database for each user as well, and then when you calculate the hash, you hash the salt plus the secret. So you store

```
salt_value  H(salt_value . secret)
```

where `.` denotes concatenation. This is more secure because if the attacker has a hash dictionary (i.e., has worked out the hash of millions of likely passwords) then he still can't break the hash: his dictionary won't have factored every possible salt value into it.

For ultra-modern security, you can also hash repeatedly. Rather than storing

```
H(salt_value . secret)
```

you store

```
H(H(H(H(...H(salt_value . secret) ...))))
```

i.e., you hash it a large number of times (say, 10,000 times). When the user logs on, hash the salt and secret repeatedly, and then compare the final result with the stored value. This is even more secure because it takes a lot longer to mount a brute force attack: the attacker will have to calculate 10,000 hashes to try a single guess at a secret.

Comment: @Ami You're welcome! Please do click the tick to select as chosen answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: I will. BTW, assuming my secret key is about 50 chars long meaning-less text, should I use salt? I know it is used when storing hashed passwords since passwords are not that variant.

Comment: You could get away with not storing salt if the secrets are randomly generated and long, yes. If they're generated by users, you need the salt, because users are notoriously bad at generating randomness.

Comment: The reason I was confused and am still, is that I worked with many APIs and never seen that they ask the user to supply the secret.

Comment: See below, its always something like this that they require you to supply in the header, just the API key and the hashed post data. Never the secret itself.   

headers = { "API-Key":      SITE_X_API_KEY,
            "API-Sign":     base64.b64encode(str(ahmac))}

Comment: By "ask the user" I mean "ask the client". If it's something stored in your browser and that automatically provides it, or similar, then it's still being provided by the user. (But this isn't the same as generation: it's only passwords that users typically generate.)

Comment: Ah, I see. If what you're required to send is the hash of the secret, then really that hash is what's needed to log in, and that hash needs to stay secret. So you hash it again and store that in the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60791/discussion-between-ami-and-chiastic-security).